# Mono WCF client can't connect from remote server

Tags: wcf, mono

I have implemented the example below with mono on centOS.

http://veritas-vos-liberabit.com/monogatari/2009/12/mono-wcf-advent-day-2-hello-wcf.html

It works fine when the client and server are on the same box.  But if I put the client on a different box I get a connection failure:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: A system exception has occurred.
System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out
```

I've run tcpdump on port 8080 on the server box and I see the request coming in, so it's not a networking issue.

Can anyone see why this wouldn't work?

Comment: What version of Mono are you running? Is it the same on both boxes? CentOS usually means 'terribly outdated software' :-(

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=275 perhaps?